# How to change panel-body background-color in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, panel

I am creating a webpage using twitter bootstrap, here i wanna change panel-body background-color form white to light-pink, but i haven't any idea that how it will be done? So ..... help me
Thank You

Comment: Try including code you have already tried, basically anything to show that you have tried some things.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The CSS being as follows (as an example) should work fine. If not then you'll need to show your code.

```
.panel-body {
background:#FFCCFF;}
```

Comment: No worries. If this answered you're question, can you accept it as the answer by clicking the tick. Thanks.